# Upgrade Elasticsearch to 5.6.3

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I get the same error with the latest version of Elasticsearch 5.6.3

```
Error: encountered environment variables that are no longer supported
Use jvm.options or ES_JAVA_OPTS to configure the JVM
ES_HEAP_SIZE=1024m: set -Xms1024m and -Xmx1024m in jvm.options or add "-
Xms1024m -Xmx1024m" to ES_JAVA_OPTS
```

I have tried to add ES_JAVA_OPTS="-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m in bin/elasticsearch but I get the same thing.

Comment: What are your settings? Can you show your elasticsearch.yaml file?

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the error message carefully.

Solution 1: open `$ES_HOME/config/jvm.options` and modify the lines starting with `-Xms` and `-Xmx`

```
-Xms1024m
-Xmx1024m
```

Or Solution 2: use an environment variable before starting Elasticsearch

```
> export ES_JAVA_OPTS="-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m"
> bin/elasticsearch
```

Comment: I have tried both solutions but i get the same error.

Comment: You must have `ES_HEAP_SIZE` specified somewhere which you need to remove